# elasticsearch pod is in pending state due to nodegroup down and up

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Describe the bug:
i have deployed elasticsearch with PVC in my EKS cluster and worked fine without issue and we tried to scale down node and scale up started facing issue and pod is in pending state.

Steps to reproduce:

```
1.helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
2.with Helm 3: helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch
3. git clone git@github.com:elastic/helm-charts.git
4. went to elastcsearch working directory and run below
5. kubectl create ns elastic
6. helm install elasticsearch . -n elastic
```

Expected behavior:

Cluster will run as expected without issue and tried to scale

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 sts/elasticsearch-master -n elastic
kubectl scale --replicas=3 sts/elasticsearch-master -n elastic
```

now my pod is pending state and stuck

```
kubectl logs pod/elasticsearch-master-0 -n elastic
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:18,156Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "version[7.17.3], pid[7], build[default/docker/5ad023604c8d7416c9eb6c0eadb62b14e766caff/2022-04-19T08:11:19.070913226Z], OS[Linux/5.4.181-99.354.amzn2.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/18/18+36]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:18,159Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:18,160Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-8450783023809497710, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms1024m, -Xmx1024m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,531Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,544Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "loaded plugin [repository-s3]" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,547Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.ml] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.ml", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,629Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.data] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.data", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,644Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/xvdck)]], net usable_space [9.6gb], net total_space [9.7gb], types [ext4]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,645Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "heap size [1gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,725Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.master] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.master", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,729Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.remote_cluster_client] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.remote_cluster_client", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,730Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.ingest] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.ingest", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,846Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "node name [elasticsearch-master-0], node ID [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ], cluster name [elasticsearch], roles [transform, data_frozen, master, remote_cluster_client, data, ml, data_content, data_hot, data_warm, data_cold, ingest]" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,848Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "legacy role settings [node.data, node.remote_cluster_client, node.ingest, node.master, node.ml] are deprecated, use [node.roles=[transform, data_frozen, master, remote_cluster_client, data, ml, data_content, data_hot, data_warm, data_cold, ingest]]", "key": "legacy role settings", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:33,947Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[controller/180] [Main.cc@122] controller (64 bit): Version 7.17.3 (Build b3cb07de236c11) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:35,946Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:37,230Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.g.ConfigDatabases", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "initialized default databases [[GeoLite2-Country.mmdb, GeoLite2-City.mmdb, GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]], config databases [[]] and watching [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ingest-geoip] for changes" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:37,232Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "initialized database registry, using geoip-databases directory [/tmp/elasticsearch-8450783023809497710/geoip-databases/VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:38,421Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.NettyAllocator", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb, heap_size=1gb}]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:38,455Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:38,556Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:39,663Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually" }
{0.0.0.0:9300}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:42,582Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks" }

(base) devops@devops-XPS-15-9570:~/Desktop/Repo$ kubectl logs pod/elasticsearch-master-0 -n elastic
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:18,156Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "version[7.17.3], pid[7], build[default/docker/5ad023604c8d7416c9eb6c0eadb62b14e766caff/2022-04-19T08:11:19.070913226Z], OS[Linux/5.4.181-99.354.amzn2.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/18/18+36]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:18,159Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:18,160Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-8450783023809497710, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms1024m, -Xmx1024m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,531Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,544Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-watcher]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,544Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "loaded plugin [repository-s3]" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,547Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.ml] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.ml", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,629Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.data] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.data", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,644Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/xvdck)]], net usable_space [9.6gb], net total_space [9.7gb], types [ext4]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,645Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "heap size [1gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,725Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.master] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.master", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,729Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.remote_cluster_client] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.remote_cluster_client", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,730Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[node.ingest] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.", "key": "node.ingest", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,846Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "node name [elasticsearch-master-0], node ID [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ], cluster name [elasticsearch], roles [transform, data_frozen, master, remote_cluster_client, data, ml, data_content, data_hot, data_warm, data_cold, ingest]" }
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:23,848Z", "level": "CRITICAL", "component": "o.e.d.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "legacy role settings [node.data, node.remote_cluster_client, node.ingest, node.master, node.ml] are deprecated, use [node.roles=[transform, data_frozen, master, remote_cluster_client, data, ml, data_content, data_hot, data_warm, data_cold, ingest]]", "key": "legacy role settings", "category": "settings" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:33,947Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "[controller/180] [Main.cc@122] controller (64 bit): Version 7.17.3 (Build b3cb07de236c11) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:35,946Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "parsed [0] roles from file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/roles.yml]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:37,230Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.g.ConfigDatabases", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "initialized default databases [[GeoLite2-Country.mmdb, GeoLite2-City.mmdb, GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]], config databases [[]] and watching [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ingest-geoip] for changes" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:37,232Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "initialized database registry, using geoip-databases directory [/tmp/elasticsearch-8450783023809497710/geoip-databases/VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:38,421Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.NettyAllocator", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb, heap_size=1gb}]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:38,455Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:38,556Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:39,663Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:41,243Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "initialized" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:41,243Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "starting ..." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:41,260Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "persistent cache index loaded" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:41,261Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "deprecation component started" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:41,458Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "publish_address {192.168.131.86:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:42,582Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:42,636Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.Coordinator", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "cluster UUID [miG-kHiRS02W-Tf8F-Nqjg]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:03:52,646Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires 2 nodes with ids [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ, r6usGUfQScG8GBc-39cang], have only discovered non-quorum [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 196 in term 1" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:02,648Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires 2 nodes with ids [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ, r6usGUfQScG8GBc-39cang], have only discovered non-quorum [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 196 in term 1" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:12,649Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires 2 nodes with ids [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ, r6usGUfQScG8GBc-39cang], have only discovered non-quorum [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 196 in term 1" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:12,650Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "timed out while waiting for initial discovery state - timeout: 30s" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:12,661Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "publish_address {192.168.131.86:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:12,661Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "started" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:14,174Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "path: /_cluster/health, params: {wait_for_status=green, timeout=1s}", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:297) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:22,650Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires 2 nodes with ids [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ, r6usGUfQScG8GBc-39cang], have only discovered non-quorum [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 196 in term 1" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:24,129Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "path: /_cluster/health, params: {wait_for_status=green, timeout=1s}", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:297) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:32,651Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires 2 nodes with ids [VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ, r6usGUfQScG8GBc-39cang], have only discovered non-quorum [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{VeyMV5ZNRMW3UyW8taNGkQ}{TogPUQAJRqqipcnACoBtoQ}{192.168.131.86}{192.168.131.86:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 196 in term 1" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-09T01:04:34,136Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "path: /_cluster/health, params: {wait_for_status=green, timeout=1s}", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:297) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]"] }
```

```
[Github link issue] (https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/1654)
```

Comment: looks like it's just of one pod did you checks for other ? are those all master node or data node also ? ref :https://discuss.elastic.co/t/master-not-discovered-or-elected-yet-an-election-requires-2-nodes-with-ids/262205/7

Answer (score 1):

You cannot scale down master nodes directly. To scale down Elasticsearch master nodes, you need to exclude the nodes from voting first. Otherwise, the pod will look up for the old master nodes (ie. old node hash).

Say you have a SatefulSet for master nodes with 3 replicas (node names: `elasticsearch-master-0`, `elasticsearch-master-1`, `elasticsearch-master-2`), and you want to scale it down to 1 replica.

- **Step 1:** Exclude `elasticsearch-master-1` and `elasticsearch-master-2` from voting:

  ```sh
  $ curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_cluster/voting_config_exclusions?node_names=elasticsearch-master-1&pretty"
  $ curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_cluster/voting_config_exclusions?node_names=elasticsearch-master-2&pretty"
  ```
- **Step 2:** Now scale down the replicas:

  ```sh
  $ kubectl scale --replicas=1 sts/elasticsearch-master -n elastic
  ```
- **Step 3:** Remove exclusion, so that once you scale up again, they can join automatically:

  ```sh
  $ curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/_cluster/voting_config_exclusions?wait_for_removal=false&pretty"
  ```

**Ref:** [Removing master-eligible nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html#modules-discovery-removing-nodes)

**N.B.:** For password-protected Elasticsearch, you need to provide the username and password with `curl` commands. Such as `$ curl -u 'username:password' ...` .